# Excel hangs during IF statement

Tags: excel, vba

I read data from a file and check if the records are already in the worksheet.

Excel freezes after processing about 60k records. If I start reading the file from the place macro stopped, it freezes again after reading another 60k records.

```
Sub aktualizacja()
    Dim koniec As Long, dlugosc As Long, pozycja As Long, numer As Long, numer2 As Long, i As Long
    Open "C:\bazy\test.dat" For Binary Access Read As #1
    dlugosc = FileLen("C:\bazy\test.dat")
    pozycja = 41
    Do
        koniec = Worksheets("Baza").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
        Get #1, pozycja, numer
        Get #1, pozycja + 4, numer2
        For i = 2 To koniec
            If Worksheets("Baza").Cells(i, 1) = numer Then
                'If Worksheets("Baza").Cells(i, 2) <> numer2 Then
                '    Worksheets("Baza").Cells(i, 2) = numer2
                'End If
                'Cells(1, 11) = i
                'Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If i > koniec Then
            Worksheets("Baza").Cells(koniec + 1, 1) = numer
            Worksheets("Baza").Cells(koniec + 1, 2) = numer2
        End If
        pozycja = pozycja + 40
    Loop Until (pozycja > dlugosc)
    Close #1
End Sub
```

When I put all the commands inside the IF statement, the macro still freezes.

Comment: what line does it freeze at?

Comment: At line 11. When I delete the following statement:  "If Worksheets("Baza").Cells(i, 1) = numer Then",  macro runs as expected...

Comment: Are there any calculations running off the cells populated?

Comment: Throw all of `Worksheets("Baza").Cells(x, 1)` into a Scripting.Dictionary. It's faster and doesn't rely upon individual reads/writes to/from the worksheet.

Comment: No, there are no calculations in worksheet...

Comment: what is the row number when it does stop, and is it the same amount of rows each time?

Comment: No, it stops at different row: sometimes at about 60k, sometimes at 30k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding something like

```
If i Mod 1000 = 0 Then DoEvents
```

in your loop to prevent locking?

Comment: No problem! By passing the control to the operating system every 1000(adjust it to your liking) iterations of your loop it will allow other operations to be processed and stop it freezing.